# How to listen to event emitted from 'root' in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, quasar

My app uses vue.js and has some integrations with vanilla js. In my vanilla js file, I create a new vue instance and emit an event from there called `annotation-click`. I can see this event in the dev tools tab.

Here is a custom event class I make:

`customevent.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default window.Event = class Event {
  constructor () {
    this.vue = new Vue()
  }

  fire (event, data = null) {
    this.vue.$emit(event, data)
  }

  listen (event, callback) {
    this.vue.$on(event, callback)
  }
}
```

And in my vanilla `js` file I emit the event like this:

```
import Event from '../utils/customevent'

var test = new Event()
...
handleClick: (view, pos, event) => {
const { schema } = view.state
const attrs = getMarkAttrs(view.state, schema.marks.annotation)
    if (attrs.href && event.target instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
        test.fire('notification', {
        title: "annotation-joe"
        })
    }
},
...
```

The event is being emitted from my main vue.js application as so:

[image]

I am listening for the event in my vue.js component, but it seems my listener is not picking the event up.

How can I properly listen to the event being emitted by `<Root>`?

And my vue.js app that imports the npm package I listen for the event like this:

```
<script>
import Event from "mypackage/utils/customevent";
var test = new Event();
...
  created() {
    test.listen("notification", function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `"I create a new vue instance and emit an event from there"` ... Do you mean you have two different Vue instances? If so, you have two roots: the component in one root, and this new Vue instance in another root.

Comment: thats correct. I've updated my question to show exactly how I am doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example to make it happen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{message}}
    </div>
    <button onclick="test()">test</button>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
 
        class MyClass extends EventTarget {
            doSomething() {
                this.dispatchEvent(new Event('something'));
            }
        }
        document.getRootNode().instance = new MyClass()

        function test() {
            const root = document.getRootNode()
            root.instance.doSomething();
        }
   
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            },
            created() {
                const root = document.getRootNode()
                root.instance.addEventListener('something', (e) => {
                    console.log('Instance fired "something".', e);
                });

            },
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this did not work for me. I am emitting the event from an npm module that I am including as a package in a different vue.js project.  The event is emitted successfully, but the listener will not pick it up correctly.